# Expected a Type

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I get an error that says 'Expected a Type' and I have no clue what that means.  Here are the lines where the error is:

```
#pragma mark - Flipside View Controller

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(XYZFlipsideViewController*)controller <=== This    
is the line with the error
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you already solved your problem? Have a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this message shows up when you have a structural typo in your file (that messes up the quotes or parenthesis balancing, etc...)

This has happened to me before and it was a header file that had a typo in it. Did you check XYZFlipsideViewController.h? Check for typos but also circular dependencies.

Comment: Also check for missing parenthesis and braces in the method above this one in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem. You should look at the elements which don't get highlighted correct, the type of the **not highlighted** element should be added to your class.

In my case, I had a problem with `UIColor`. This happens if `UIKit.h` is not included, so xCode doesn't know how to handle the used classes.

In your case, ** XYZFlipsideViewController.h** should be the problem. It might be possible you have also to include `UIKit.h` by adding

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

If this doesn't fix your problem have a look at other elements and there type and try to include the `framework` from iOS.